# Split a string and make a list in java

Tags: java, string, list, loops, split

I have a string A/B/C/D in java.
I need to create a list with elements like this.

```
1/A
2/A/B
3/A/B/C
4/A/B/C/D
```

Also this should be configurable.
i.e., if fromValue is 2 and toValue is 4 then the elements in the list should be as below.

```
2/A/B
3/A/B/C
4/A/B/C/D
```

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: please make an effort, and share your [mcve] in the OP

Comment: Is the `toValue` always going to be the number of strings between slashes?  Your question implies it might be different.  For example, what if `toValue` was`3` but the source string was stlll `A/B/C/D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first build a `List` from splitting the string on `/`. Then, iterate from the starting index to the end of the `List`, concatenating together the first certain number of elements in the `List` with `String.join`.

For example:

```java
var s = "A/B/C/D";
int from = 1;
var parts = List.of(s.split("/"));
var res = IntStream.rangeClosed(from, parts.size()).mapToObj(
              i -> i + "/" + String.join("/", parts.subList(0, i))).toList();
```

Comment: Good, but I hate to see lower case L used as a variable. Anything else is better.

Comment: @DavidConrad Good point. I've renamed to `parts`.